# EMC Documentum- Service method "Execute" invocation failed

Tags: documentum, emc, documentum-dfs

I have integrated documentum with our .net application. In this application we are uploading a document which will be stored on documentum. But when I am trying to do this it is throwing following errors.

1. Service method "Execute" invocation failed.
2. There was no endpoint listening at
   `https://dfs-uat.abc.com:800/services/core/QueryService` that
   could accept the message.  This is often caused by an incorrect
   address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more
   details.
3. Unable to connect to the remote server

it is working fine in other laptops it is not working in mine. I am clueless what actually is going on. any help can be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

at Emc.Documentum.FS.Runtime.Context.Impl.ClientReflectionServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Emc.Documentum.FS.Runtime.Context.Impl.UcfClientInvocationHandler.Invoke(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Emc.Documentum.FS.Runtime.Context.Impl.SoapClientInvocationHandler.Invoke(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] arguments)
   at Emc.Documentum.FS.Runtime.Context.Impl.HttpSessionInvocationHandler.Invoke(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Emc.Documentum.FS.Runtime.Context.Impl.ReturnedContentTransformationHandler.Invoke(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Emc.Documentum.FS.Runtime.Context.Impl.OperationOptionsHandler.Invoke(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Emc.Documentum.FS.Runtime.Context.Impl.ContextThreadLocalInvocationHandler.Invoke(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Emc.Documentum.FS.Runtime.Context.Impl.ServiceContextInvocationHandler.Invoke(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at $Proxy1.Emc.Documentum.FS.Services.Core.IQueryService.Execute(Query , QueryExecution , OperationOptions )
   at DocumentumSample.DClient.DQueryServiceClient.GetObjectIdByFileOrFolderName(String fileOrFolderName) in C:\tfs\1TRAM_TRAMS\TRAM\MAIN\DVT\WEB\MAIN\TRAMS.Documentum\DClient\DQueryServiceClient.cs:line 53

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Emc.Documentum.FS.Services.Core.QueryServicePort.execute(executeRequest request)
   at Emc.Documentum.FS.Services.Core.QueryServicePortClient.Emc.Documentum.FS.Services.Core.QueryServicePort.execute(executeRequest request)
   at Emc.Documentum.FS.Services.Core.QueryServicePortClient.Execute(Query query, QueryExecution execution, OperationOptions options)

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()

Comment: you didn't supply any stacktrace, please do so

Comment: since you are mentioning connection problems are you sure you configured proper connection details

Comment: Thanks miki.I have added stack trace.Actually it is not working in my laptop.it is working in other laptops.

Comment: Problem was resolved. In internet options I actually checked the option "use a proxy  server for your Lan". Since I am running as proxy server that is the reason why I am not able to connect to end point.To resolve go to this path Internet options-->connections-->Lan settings-->uncheck the checkbox "use a proxy  server for your Lan"